# Dynamically create polymer element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have defined login element as follows:

```html
<polymer-element name="my-login" extends="form">
  <template> ...</template>
```

and dart class as follows:

```dart
@CustomTag('my-login')
  class MyLogin extends PolymerElement { .... }
```

In the main application component, I am trying to create my-login as follows:

```dart
 MyLogin p =  new Element.tag("my-login", "FormElement");
```

This generates exception:

Exception: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'MyLogin' of 'p'.

The code works if "extends=form" is removed from polymer-element declaration :

```html
 <polymer-element name="my-login">
```

and created as follows:

```dart
MyLogin p =  new Element.tag("my-login");
```

How to dynamically create custom element that extends other HTML element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should instantiate it as

```dart
Element y = new Element.tag('form', 'my-login');
```

What seems not to work is

```dart
MyLogin y = new Element.tag('form', 'my-login');
```

this should result in the HTML for the inserted element

```html
<form is="my-login"></form>
```

Comment: That's interesting. @zoechi Does attempting to access MyLogin's members throw exceptions?

Comment: @Xerosigma I checked if the correct tag HTML was generated for the inserted element. I also couldn't properly access the properties of the object but I couldn't find the time yet to examine it properly. I guess this is a bug in Polymer.dart.

Comment: wired,

Element polyItem = new Element.tag("custom-project-button");
polyItem.project = k.toString();

does not work in mz new project, but it did work in my rainbow project

Comment: What do you mean by `does not work`. Maybe you missed to import the element somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

```dart
factory MyLogin() => document.createElement("form", "my-login");
```

Then you can just call:

```dart
MyLogin login = new MyLogin();
```

This works for me.