# Register Polymer Class Name

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

So i've been trying to add a PolymerElement dynamically to an other PolymerElement.

```dart
 MyPolyElem newRow = new MyPolyElem();
  (newRow as MyPolyElem).type = type;  // -> Exception
  panelBody.append(newRow);
```

`Exception: Uncaught Error: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'MyPolyElem ' in type cast.`

If I try to access type, it says that newRow is a HtmlElement and does not have "type". If I try to cast it, is says that its not a subtype of HtmlElement.

```dart
@CustomTag('poly-elem')
class MyPolyElem extends PolymerElement {
    @published String type = "int";

    void attached() {
        super.attached();
    }
    factory MyPolyElem() => document.createElement("poly-elem");
    MyPolyElem.created() : super.created() {}
}
```

Apparently, if i create a Polymer Element dynamically, its a HtmlElement. If i would write in the the HTML as tag and query for it, its a MyPolyElem. So i'd like to know how i could register the Name of the Class for this Tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically created elements can be cast like declaratively added elements.
I'm pretty sure this doesn't work in your case because Polymer is not yet fully initialized.

See [how to implement a main function in polymer apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982489) for how to initialize Polymer properly when you have a custom `main()` method.

I never used `document.createElement()` to create a Polymer element dynamically. I used `new Element.tag('xxx-yyy')` instead. If the `main()` method is not the cause you might try this (see also [Dynamically create polymer element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474071))

Even though you create it dynamically you need to add an import like when you add it decoratively.

Comment: Where did you add this code (where is it called from) if not from `main()`?

Comment: Its called from a function, which is called by a Button from another CustomElement.

new Element.tag(..) returns a HtmlElement

Comment: This was actually the case...
I didnt import the html since I did not use the tag in the HTML file...